# Setting up a local copy from a production site

Tags: localhost, xampp, production

I'm having an issue with a local copy of a live WordPress site. The local site itself `http://localhost/mywordpress/` works as I did the following:

- copy the production WP folder;
- import the MySQL database to the local db with the same credentials
  as production (I've already created the local db and username same as
  production);
- update the `home` and `siteurl` to localhost in `wp_options`;
- update `wp_postmeta`, setting `meta_value` to replace
  `http://www.example.com` with `http://localhost/mywordpress` delete
  the `wp-config.php` file so that I can set up the configuration
  manually;

Upon the setup, I am able to view the site's homepage, but accessing `http://localhost/mywordpress/wp-login.php` produces a 403 error message.

To get around this, I copied the code to a `wp-login2.php`, and I can see the page without issue. However, upon submit, I get redirected to the production site. Seeing this, I thought that maybe changing the instances of wp-login.php to `wp-login2.php` would help, but same issue occurs, except that the page is a 404 since it doesn't exist in production.

When clicking on other links on the homepage, I get redirected to the XAMPP dashboard page. This despite the link addressing to `http://localhost/mywordpress/somelink/`

I apologize for the overload in details.

Added detail, when accessing `http://localhost/mywordpress/wp-admin/`, I get redirected to the production site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it turned out to be a plugins issue. So I ran the following query:

`update wp_options set option_value = 'a:0:{}' where option_name = 'active_plugins'`

Answer (score 3):

It is painful to clone the wordpress site sometimes when the site has a lot of plugins and custom code.

I did it manually before. But I am using "Duplicator" plugin to handle this now.

Please check:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: The backups are scheduled on the production site using BackupWordPress plugin, and I'm trying to import the backup files into a staging server running XAMPP.

Comment: Will this take care of the naming changes when cloning to a local server?

Comment: It will take care the changes of the domain or the path.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoon. Ok, so what I did finally was disable all plugins via MySQL:

`update wp_options set option_value = '' where option_name = 'active_plugins'`. The site is up and I'm able to log in. However, when I try accessing `https://localhost/mywordpress/some_link`, I get redirected to the XAMPP dashboard. Any suggestions? I'm checking the permalinks, but nothing stands out for me as 'post name' is selected.

Comment: Sorry, disregard. I fat-fingered the db update to point to links that do not exist.